# Encoding problem using rvest for obtaining coordinates in R?

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding, tidyverse, rvest

I am trying to obtain decimal coordinates from a table in wikipedia. The code below gets me all the way to having a column for latitude and a column for longitude, but I am failing at the final step of converting the `longitude` column from character to numeric. In contrast, the `latitude` column converts fine.

The problem seems to be a 'hidden' character at the end of each string in the `longitude` column (`str_length` 'counts' one extra character than is visible in the column values).

Is this an encoding issue? How do I convert the `longitude` column to numeric?

This code seems to get me most of the way:

```
# load packages
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)

# get coordinates data
webpage_url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Premier_League_stadiums"
webpage <- xml2::read_html(webpage_url)

# put web data into dataframe
df1 <- rvest::html_table(webpage, fill = TRUE)[[1]] 

df2 <- df1 %>% 
  # split different coordinate formats
  mutate(temp_Coordinates = str_split(string = Coordinates, pattern = " / ")) %>% 
  # one coordinate format per row
  unnest(cols = temp_Coordinates) %>% 
  group_by(Stadium) %>% 
  # keep only 3rd row per stadium, i.e. decimal format of coordinates
  filter(row_number() == 3) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  # seperate coordinate pairs into individual columns for latitude and longitude
  separate(temp_Coordinates, c("latitude","longitude"), sep = " ") %>% 
  # remove semi-colon from end of latitude string
  mutate(latitude = str_replace(latitude, ";", ""))
```

The problem seems to be with this final step, converting `longitude` from character to numeric (resulting instead in a column of NAs):

```
df3 <- df2 %>% 
  # convert latitude from character to numeric 
  mutate(latitude = as.numeric(latitude)) %>% 
  # convert longitude from character to numeric
  mutate(longitude = as.numeric(longitude))
```

Manually assigning a copy-and-pasted value from `longitude` returns this error (note the appearance of the weird question mark character when the string is pasted into the console);

x <- "-2.96083�"
Error: EOF whilst reading MBCS char at line 2

Anyone know how to change the format so that I can convert to numeric?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `Encoding(longitude) = 'UTF-8'` ?

Comment: I have, but with the same outcome. `Encoding(df2$longitude)` also suggests the column was already in UTF-8 anyway. Thanks though.

Comment: what would be an example output row format please?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, sorry. My problem is with the formatting of characters in a specific colum, I think. The desired output is to be able to convert form character to numeric.

Comment: So what would that conversion look like for one row in your final df? The final lat and lon values.

Comment: I may still have misunderstood, but the desired output would look (at least _visibly_) like any row from `df2` in the code above, e.g. `df2 %>% filter(row_number() == 1)`. i.e. it would look like it does now, but the lat and lon values would be numeric and not character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull values from a different set of nodes and assign to the dataframe

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

webpage_url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Premier_League_stadiums"
webpage <- read_html(webpage_url) 
df1 <- webpage %>% html_node('table') %>% html_table(fill = T)
geos <- webpage %>% html_nodes('.geo') %>% html_text() %>% str_split_fixed(., ';',2)
df1$latitude <- geos[, 1] %>% as.double()
df1$longitude <- geos[, 2] %>% as.double()

print(head(df1,1))
```